Powershell script run by Task Scheduler - exit code not reflected by task
I would be glad if someone can help me.
I have a PowerShell script, which, in case of some error (try-catch block), exits with some exit code using the command exit 1.
This script is called by a task in Task Scheduler, which is set up to run powershell.exe with parameters -File C:\folder\script.ps1. Also, the task is set up so that if the task fails, it should retry to run it 5 more times.
The problem I am facing is that even if my script exits with an error code and I can see in the UI, that the 'last run status' is 0x1, the task still thinks it ran successfully and does not retry run the script again.
I tried to google something, and also I tried many different advice I found online, but nothing helped me.
If you have any ideas, I would be glad for anything.

so from task schedulers perspective its launching a exe (the shell), so it can't see what happens inside that shell or make decisions on it. its the shell itself that the task scheduler can invoke and apply return logic to.  Take a look at this to see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50200325/returning-an-exit-code-from-a-powershell-script .

Try giving it a different error code, like 100. 1 could be seen as ok or info etc.

What happens if you code the error detection and recovery  into the task the scheduler runs, and have that task invoke the code to be tested?

Hello everybody, thank you for all the responses. I understand how the task scheduler "thinks" about running the PowerShell scripts, etc. In the end, I have implemented the exception handling into the script, and I won't use the task scheduler's repetition.
